# How to add and change a class on the body tag/div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to add a class on the `body` tag/div and on the anchor tag when I click an anchor tag.

[Here is my jsFiddle File.](http://jsfiddle.net/4nFUd/)

```
<div id="body">
 <!-- background image here -->

</div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">First Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Third Option</a></li>
</ul>​
```

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Please post what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/4nFUd/5/

Add an event listener to the click and modify as needed...

```
<script>
$('ul').on('click','a',function(){
    $('#body').css('background',$(this).attr('rel'));
    $(this).addClass($(this).attr('rel'));
});
</script>
<div id="body">
 <!-- background image here -->

</div>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#" rel="blue">First Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="green">Second Option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="yellow">Third Option</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should mention that JQuery is being used in the above code snippet. Otherwise it wont work.

Comment: @Amareswar It is asked for jQuery, so I think it don't needs to be metioned again

Comment: @SvenBieder got it. Sorry about that. OP did not use any JQuery functions in his fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick.

```
$("li a").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("class1");
  $("#body").addClass("class2");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here it is, ad class to body and anchor itself
  http://jsfiddle.net/testtracker/4nFUd/2/

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
$('#body').addClass('classname-tobody');
$(this).addClass('classname-toanchor');
});​
```